# How to isolate timestamp and expression from log file using regex

Tags: python, regex, parsing, python-re

I have a log file which looks something like this:

> **04:26:24.664149** [PHY1   ] [I] [ 4198] PUCCH: cc=0; rnti=0x46, f=1a, n_pucch=12, dmrs_corr=0.995, **snr=13.2** dB, corr=0.974, ack=1, ta=0.1 us

> 04:26:24.665067 [PHY0   ] [D] [ 4199] Worker 0 running

> 04:26:24.665166 [PHY0   ] [D] [ 4199] Sending to radio

> **04:26:24.666220** [PHY1   ] [I] [ 4200] PUCCH: cc=0; rnti=0x46, f=1, n_pucch=0, dmrs_corr=0.270, **snr=-4.3** dB, corr=0.000, sr=no, ta=-9.0 us

> 04:26:24.666288 [PHY1   ] [D] [ 4200] Sending to radio

> **04:26:24.667305** [PHY0   ] [I] [ 4201] PUCCH: cc=0; rnti=0x46, f=2, n_pucch=0, dmrs_corr=0.989, **snr=15.4** dB, corr=0.998, cqi=15 (cc=0), ta=0.2 us

> 04:26:24.667338 [MAC    ] [D] [ 4201] ra_tbs=72/144, tbs_bytes=15, tbs=144, mcs=2

I am wanting to isolate the lines  where there is a snr={value} entry, and also to copy the timestamp associated with that entry. I have put in **bold** the parts of the example I am wanting to extract with regex.

I have tried many different regex expressions to try and extract these two bits of information from my log file (on the lines in which they are present). It is important to note that the **snr** value can be positive or negative, and can vary from -999.9 dB to 999.9 dB. The timestamp is present on every line of the log file.

An example of my expected output would be: **04:26:24.664149 snr=13.2**

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one approach using `re.findall`:

```py
inp = """04:26:24.664149 [PHY1   ] [I] [ 4198] PUCCH: cc=0; rnti=0x46, f=1a, n_pucch=12, dmrs_corr=0.995, **snr=13.2** dB, corr=0.974, ack=1, ta=0.1 us
04:26:24.665067 [PHY0   ] [D] [ 4199] Worker 0 running
04:26:24.665166 [PHY0   ] [D] [ 4199] Sending to radio
04:26:24.666220 [PHY1   ] [I] [ 4200] PUCCH: cc=0; rnti=0x46, f=1, n_pucch=0, dmrs_corr=0.270, **snr=-4.3** dB, corr=0.000, sr=no, ta=-9.0 us
04:26:24.666288 [PHY1   ] [D] [ 4200] Sending to radio"""

matches = re.findall("(\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\.\d{6})[^\r\n]*(snr=-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)", inp)
print(matches)
```

This prints:

```
[('04:26:24.664149', 'snr=13.2'), ('04:26:24.666220', 'snr=-4.3')]
```